# How can I view a PDF without buffering or lag when scrolling?

Tags: pdf, scrolling, adobe-reader

I am using PDFs that take about a second per page to load.  I want the entire PDF document to load into the cache all at once so that I can scroll between pages with no buffering or delay.  Currently Adobe Reader seems to load 2-3 pages at a time, so if I scroll down 3 pages I can instantly scroll back up to page 1.  But if I scroll to page 30, it unloads pages 1-27 so it takes about 20 seconds to scroll back up to page 1.  This is really bugging me and I want Adobe to stop unloading pages.

I'm willing to switch to another reader if that would help.  Firefox's integrated PDF reader does the same thing.

Comment: You might experiment with some of the free alternative readers, such as Nitro PDF and Sumatra, to see if they offer an advantage. See http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-reader/ for a list; Sumatra is probably the quickest to install.

Comment: That solves the problem.  I already tried Foxit Reader and Nitro PDF, but I just tried Sumatra and it really is lightning fast compared to to the alternatives, and there is no longer a noticeable loading time for my PDFs.

Comment: Glad it helped. Nitro PDF offers a printer driver, but Sumatra is faster, so I install both.

Comment: FYI: Assuming you have adobe reader 9 or above it supports GPU acceleration so the faster your video card the faster it processes the pages.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik If you're looking for a lightweight open source printer driver alternative to use along with Sumatra, I suggest https://www.cogniview.com/cc-free-pdf-converter

Comment: @cybernard, Adobe Reader is useful but heavyweight, and had many security issues (see https://helpx.adobe.com/security.html#reader for just recent ones) so I prefer not to install it.